How to store a lot of small text files with fast access?
I need to store a lot of small text files (~3 billions and it grows by 70m every day) with size from 100B to a few kB. I can group them, but group will have unpredictable number of items: from 1 to 100m. There are 2 requirements:

quick access by id (each file has a unique key for it)
storing them as compact as possible, ideally with compression

Actually I can do a hierarchical structure and just store them in filesystem (I can use ZFS as well for compression on top of it), however I'm afraid I waste too much space because average size of file is about only 1Kb.
I looked at HBase and Cassandra, I thinks they are overkill for me, I don't need sharding and other their features. Recently I've found RocksDB. Maybe some lightweight solution exists?

This is a very good use case for Cassandra.
You can use the file ID as the partition key and having billions and billions of files (partitions) would not be a problem at all and retrieval by ID will be very fast. Store the contents of the text file in a column of type CQL text. Since it's just a bunch of text, it will be heavily compressed automatically on disk.
Here is an example table definition:
CREATE TABLE files_by_id (
    file_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    content text
)

Of course, you can store the file ID as CQL type uuid or even text depending on what the ID is. Cheers!
